# Android call my own LOCAL WebService (Symfony) in localhost

Tags: android, api, rest, symfony, localhost

i have build an app on Symfony and a WebService REST for this app.

I have already build an Android application on the same idea of my Symfony project and i want to use the API (I'm on localhost) of my Symfony Application for consuming my Webservice in Android.

How can I do that without an OVH server or something else ?

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to send HTTP request to your webservice by specifing the endpoint as your local IP address.

You can use a third-part library as https://github.com/square/retrofit to do that properly, or with the native android http request manager : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Unless the symfony server is **running on the Android device itself** it must be addressed by a routable IP address or hostname, not "localhost" which would only work in the case where the Android device is talking to itself.